# How to quickly close multiple windows from the same application via the taskbar?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, user-interface

Closing multiple app instances/tabs/windows requires a lot of waiting and chasing of close buttons.

When I need to close multiple instances/tabs of an app in the Windows 10 taskbar is there a way to keep the previews from moving or to move uniformly such that I don't have to wait for an animation and then move the cursor to where the next window I want to close has shifted?

**Edit:**
Specifically closing multiple items, but not all.

Comment: Are you talking about only closing some of the open windows or all of them?

Comment: only closing some, good clarification.

Comment: Right click, close all windows would work otherwise.  In fact sometimes it's faster to close all windows and then reopen the windows I need.  Most tabbed applications already have UI options for this use case, "close others," "close tabs to the right",  Chrome does a nice thing where the next tab's close button ends up where the previous one was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could disable the thumbnail preview altogether with the following registry setting:

- Go to the registry key
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband`
- Create a new 32-bit `DWORD` value named `NumThumbnails` and leave it's
  value set to `0`
- Restart or sign out

The resulting behavior change is below:

[image]

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, I'm not sure how this makes it easier to close multiple windows.  It looks like the ExtendedUIHoverTime setting just delays the previews from showing when hovering the app icon in the task bar.  If I click on the icon to show the list of open windows they still show as previews.

Comment: @JoelAnderson I apologize, I was referencing the incorrect setting. I've updated my answer with the correct registry setting.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple windows open, you can go to Task View by clicking the icon next to the search bar. It looks like this;

[image]

You will then see a screen with all the open windows.

[image]
[Image source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_personal/how-to-manage-running-programs-and-virtual/17d068b7-5e4a-4351-a019-afa528a81538)

From there, you can click the `X` in the upper right corner of the windows you want to close.

Comment: Same problem there too.  As soon as one window is closed the rest of them shift around with an animation.  Which is no big deal if you want to close fewer than 3 windows at a time.  but, if you want to close many windows there is a lot of effort put into chasing close buttons around the screen etc.

Comment: I see. Don't know if you are going to get there with WIndows. :-/